# CakePHP + Knockout.js?

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I am thinking about writing a web app using Knockout.js for the client-side and CakePHP for the server-side. Is this advisable? How can I save/load data to/from a database since it seems that Knockout.js saves out to JSON? Maybe there's another client-side JS library that would work better with CakePHP?

Thanks, just looking for your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using knockoutjs with cakephp.  Knockoutjs is designed to be backend agnostic, meaning you can use it with any server side technology, it also does not assume anything about how you are communicating with the server.

While the view model on the client side is almost identical to a json object, it is possible to data bind to a form and its associated form elements, which can then be submitted as a normal html form.